# Python scraping last post date using beutifulsoup from a complicated forum

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I'm trying to scrape some data from a forum (Specifically DATE of last post), worked fine with other elements for this exact forum however the date element has super weird class and no matter how many elements I add, I cannot target it specifically to only get it Once..

This is my code snippet used to only get the date of last post.

```
import re
import urllib
import os

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pip._vendor import requests


def make_soup(url):
   thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
   soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
   return soupdata

soup2 = make_soup('http://forums.automotive.com/69/1052/general-auto-repair/page1.html')

lPostDate = ""

for postDate2 in soup2.findAll('td', {"class": "brdr1 pad10_20 bgrnd19"}):
    lPostDate += (postDate2.get_text("\n", strip=True)[0:10] + "\n")
    print(lPostDate)
```

However this is my output each time:

```
10/06/15 0

10/06/15 0
137

10/06/15 0
137
49976

10/06/15 0
137
49976
02/04/17 1

10/06/15 0
137
49976
02/04/17 1
1

10/06/15 0
137
49976
02/04/17 1
1
130

10/06/15 0
137
49976
02/04/17 1
1
130
01/30/17 0

10/06/15 0
137
49976
02/04/17 1
1
130
01/30/17 0
0

10/06/15 0
137
49976
02/04/17 1
1
130
01/30/17 0
0
145
```

And this continues on for 1080 lines... Any tips would be appreciated. Done so with another forum using "re.compile" and that worked absolutelly fine, however this forum is a lot more picky in naming it's elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for tr in soup2.findAll('tr', id=re.compile('Thread')):
    text = tr('td')[2].get_text(strip=True)
    date = text.split('By')[0]  # strip the By:...
    print(date)
```

out:

```
10/06/15 05:47 PM
02/04/17 11:58 PM
01/30/17 08:44 PM
01/26/17 12:44 AM
01/22/17 06:25 PM
01/19/17 02:23 PM
01/18/17 10:52 PM
01/18/17 04:57 PM
01/17/17 04:15 PM
01/17/17 04:12 PM
01/14/17 08:34 PM
01/12/17 08:00 PM
01/10/17 02:21 PM
01/10/17 01:00 PM
01/08/17 11:45 PM
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks a lot. Was overcomplicating things :)